# Retrieve content field from html span

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have the following html code inside an object:

`<span itemprop="price" content="187">187,00&nbsp;€</span>`

My idea is to get the contet of the span object (the price). In order to do so, I am doing the following:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(res.content)
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()')
print(float(prices[0].split()[0].replace(',','.')))
```

Here, `res.content` contains inside the span object shown above. As you can see, I am getting the price from `187,00&nbsp;€` (after some modifications) when it would be easier to get it from the "content" tag inside span. I have tried using:

`tree.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/content()')`

But it does not work. Is there a way to retrieve this data? I am open to use any other libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) library for html parsing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup('<span itemprop="price" content="187">187,00&nbsp;€</span>', 'html.parser')
content = d.find('span')['content']
```

Output:

```
'187'
```

To be event more specific, you can provide the `itemprop` value:

```
content = d.find('span', {'itemprop':'price'})['content']
```

To get the content between the tags, use `soup.text`:

```
content = d.find('span', {'itemprop':'price'}).text
```

Output:

```
'187,00\xa0€'
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for. I find the code better using `BeautifulSoup` than only `requests` and `html`. One more question, what if I want to get now `187,00&nbsp;€`. What should I put instead of `['content']`? I mean, getting the actual content of the div/span.

Comment: @luis.galdo You can use `soup.text`. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="price"]')
for price in prices:
    print(price.get("content"))
```

Comment: This also works, but I decided to give the other answer as correct since it fits better my situation!